# alternate for Oleb DB importing excel file

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

Maybe someone can help me with the following problem:
I want to import a excel file and read the columns in to the database. I used OleDB provider so far:

```
  string constr = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0", path);

            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(constr))
            {
                conn.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [Sheet1$]", conn);
                OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

is there an alternate for doing this without OleDB? im getting the following errormessage:The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.  and i  dont have the option to install ole DB on the environment where the application is running.

thanks

Comment: Ace requires a license for Microsoft office to be installed on a PC.  I've been told you can download an installer from MSDN to install ACE without office.  I've tried a couple of times doing this without an admin account and was not successful.  Other people claim they have been able to install ACE.

Comment: okay thanks for the info! But i hope it is possible to do it different programaticaly

Comment: You either use Microsoft Jet which comes with windows but only works with xls files, or ACE which work with xlsx files and doesn't come with windows.  You can use the Excel Interop interface which is inefficient, and Open XML.  There are only 4 choices unless you want to use text like CSV.